# Viewing a part of the screen in a window on Linux

Tags: unity, xorg, xserver

I plan to make a presentation with a live demo using my wide screen Ubuntu 12.10 Laptop and a projector. My plan is to connect the projector as a second (small) display and put my slides and live-demo there. It would be convenient, if I could see the projector display on my laptop LCD screen within a window (no zoom or stretch needed). So my question is:

How can I see selected part of a screen within a window?

Thank you for your suggestions!

PS
Other possibilities are

- typing on laptop and looking on the projector screen and not at the audience
- Cloning laptop display to the projector display: zooming/stretching wide screen to a small projector screen and also being unable to put some private (like timer) information on the laptop screen.

Original on Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97005/49672

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hier ist a repost of the [answer from Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97005/viewing-a-part-of-the-screen-in-a-window-on-linux/97417#97417) from [jofel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/15241/jofel):

(Please, go to the original answer and give +1 there, if you like it)

---

> You can achieve this using the xrandr extension. Read [this wiki
>   page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2) and/or [this article](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/dohmen/) for more information.
>
> Make sure that the virtual desktop is not greater than your laptop
>   screen. With the `--pos` option of xrandr you can then mirror parts of
>   your screen to the projector, e.g. for a 1600x900 laptop screen and a
>   1024x768 projector at position 100,100:
>
> ```
> xrandr --fb 1600x900 --output VGA --mode 1024x768 --pos 100x100
> ```
>
> For a dual-head presentation, you can also use the following tools
>   (depending on the format of the presentation you uses):
>
> - [pdfpc](http://davvil.github.io/pdfpc/)
> - [pympress](http://pympress.org/)
> - LibreOffice Impress (perhaps also OpenOffice  Impress)